# How do I update create route from rails 3 to 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form tag which is seen below, when I try to run the page I get the error: No route matches {:action=>"create", :type=>"new", :controller=>"lists"}

```
  <%= form_for @list, :url => {:action => "create", :type => "new"}, :html => {:multipart => true,:role=>"form"} do |f| %>
```

In my routes file i have a line--  `resources :lists`
I thought the line above in the routes file is supposed to create correct routes for me.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url option needs a controller if you're going to format things this way... and there isn't a type option in [url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for)... so it should probably look like this:

```
<%= form_for @list, :url => {:controller => 'lists', :action => "create"}, :html => {:multipart => true,:role=>"form"} do |f| %>
```

Or without the hash rockets:

```
<%= form_for @list, url: { controller: 'lists', action: "create" }, html: { multipart: true, role: "form"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Is there another way of formatting the form_for tag?

Comment: I got this to work, the only thing i changed was i gave a specific url

Answer (score 0):

check the method, create must be sent via POST as

```
<%= form_for @list, as: :list :url => lists_path, method: :post do |f| %>
```